# Eclipse inserting arg0, arg1 etc. instead of proper parameter names when overriding Android methods

Tags: android, eclipse, ide

When I override methods from the Android classes in Eclipse, I get useless parameter names like "arg0", "arg1" etc. For example when overriding methods from `SQLiteOpenHelper` I get:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

I've found various posts about this but none of the accepted solutions seem to work for me. It is also strange because it only seems to happen some of the time. For example the constructors in the above test had correctly named parameters.

I **have** got "Documentation for Android SDK" installed in the Android SDK Manager for Android 4.4.2. Do I still need to manually attach the docs (or even source?) somehow for this to work reliably, and if so how do I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about Android specifically, but for Eclipse in general it is the source that is needed for this.

Comment: I guess it happens because there is no already declaration of such types in the code, try to make some variables of int, SqlLightDatabse and give it meaningful name and then override method, see if it adopts it or not

Comment: @greg-449 - Thank you! I think that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @greg-449 mentioned in the comments, the **Android source needs to be attached** for this to work.

**Following the steps in [this link](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/adding-android-source-code-and-javadoc-in-eclipse/) seems to fix this.**

In case the link is broken in future, the steps are:

1. Download "Sources for Android SDK" using the SDK Manager
2. Right click `android.jar` in the Eclipse Package Explorer (under the `Android {version}` node), and click properties
3. Under "Java Source Attachment", enter the path to the downloaded source directory which is along the lines of **{sdk}/sources/android-{version}**

I then get this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

**UPDATE**: For reference, a similar problem occurs in Android Studio (v0.4.2 at the time of writing). Sources can be attached via File -> Other Settings -> Default Project Structure, select SDKs, android platform and add the source in the "Sourcepath" tab.