# Names of variables when overriding a method

Tags: java, android

Basically when I'm overriding a method in Android Studio I get parameter names like, for example:

```
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}
```

while other people (from tutorials etc.) get parameter names like:

```
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}
```

which at least gives some context with its name.

Is there a setting to improve the generated parameter names?

Comment: It may be a problem of source attachment, see the _UPDATE_ section (which refers to Android Studio)  of the accepted answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140156/eclipse-inserting-arg0-arg1-etc-instead-of-proper-parameter-names-when-overrid

Comment: names are usually what you mention in your base methods.

Answer (score -1):

```
    parameters names are depends on how to method is written in interface or abstract class.

    interface A {
        void add(int numberOne, int numberTwo);
    }

    interface C {
        void addition(int i, int j);
    }

    class B implements A, C {
            @Override
            public void add(int numberOne, int numberTwo) {

            }

            @Override
            public void addition(int i, int j) {

            }
    }

so its clear that parameters of override method is depends on how it is written in interface or abstract class.
```